# How would I render my .js.erb file here?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form that hits a controller action. The controller action redirects to another action (my `create` action) and I have this code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

I have a create.js.erb file that I want to render after that. However, the file is not being rendered. I was thinking that it was not rendering because I needed to add `:remote => true` to the form, but this does not make a difference because the first controller action that my form hits is not the one that renders the .js.erb file.

How should I set this up so that I render my .js.erb file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're describing correctly, you are hitting one controller action that then redirects to another action using the `redirect_to` method, and you want the second action to respond with a javascript template.  If that's the case, you can specify the format in your redirect request using the `:format` option.  So you could do something like

```
redirect_to :action => 'show', :format => 'js'
```

Comment: would this work? `redirect_to "/results/#{params[:search][:search]}/1", :format => 'js'`

Comment: No, but this would: `redirect_to "/results/#{params[:search][:search]}/1.js"`.  I think you need to study how routing work in rails a bit more.  Try running `rake routes` and you'll see how `:format` comes into play.